# Passing credentials from MVC Web App to WCF Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, security, asp.net-mvc-4, wcf-security

I have a MVC 4 web app which is using Forms authentication to verfiy the user's username and password. The web app makes calls to a number of WCF Services which also require the user's username and password to verify the user has access to the service.

What is the best method for "keeping track" of the user's username and password in the web app to then pass to the WCF service?

From what I've read it sounds like using the session state to store the password is not a good idea but I'm not sure what the best alternative is.

Comment: What about the database?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Robert. If I store it in the database to then use later during the user's session wont that mean that I will have to store it in clear text though?

Comment: Not if you encrypt it.  But the same would be true of any other storage medium

Comment: Having a look at setting up a STS service to see if that might be a better option.